# Unable to compile SimpleTimer code - Exit status 1

Tags: timers

I downloaded the SimpleTimer library from the Arduino's library manager and navigated to Arduino Playground website for some sample code for testing - [SimpleTimer - Arduino Playground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer/). After copying the following code into the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>

// the timer object
SimpleTimer timer;

// a function to be executed periodically
void repeatMe() {
    Serial.print("Uptime (s): ");
    Serial.println(millis() / 1000);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    timer.setInterval(1000, repeatMe);
}

void loop() {
    timer.run();
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'SimpleTimer::setInterval(int, void (&)())'
```

Please help me out here as I am doing everything according to the instructions given in the arduino playground page of SimpleTimer.

Comment: Did you install the library?

Comment: `int setInterval(long d, timer_callback f)` the function needs a `long` value, you're trying to pass an integer.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Arduino libraries called “SimpleTimer”. [According
to arduinolibraries.info](https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/simple-timer), the one you get through the
library manager is [Alexander Kiryanenko's SimpleTimer](https://github.com/kiryanenko/SimpleTimer). The
one described in Arduino Playground is [Marcello Romani's
version](https://github.com/marcelloromani/Arduino-SimpleTimer). You should try the examples that come with the
specific library you install.